# Test whether vb.net code working or not

Tags: vb.net, authentication, active-directory

Maybe this is a stupid question but I am really new in this field..
I am working about authentication in vb.net using AD. After doing some searching, I found a lot of codes related to this. for example:

```
Private m_ServerName As String 
Private m_LoginName As String
Private m_Authenicate As String 
Public Sub New() 
' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer. 
InitializeComponent()  

' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call. 
m_ServerName = DOMAIN_NAME ' Your Domain Name 
m_LoginName = Environment.UserName.ToString 
m_Authenicate = My.User.Name  
End Sub  

Public Function IsLogonValid() As Boolean 
Dim m_LoginName As String 
Dim dirEntry As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry 
Dim dirSearcher As System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
lblStatus.Text = "Validating User Account"  

Try  
m_LoginName = Environment.UserName.ToString 'The logged in user ID 
dirEntry = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & DOMAIN_NAME)  
dirSearcher = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)  
dirSearcher.Filter = "(samAccountName=" & m_LoginName & ")" 
       'Use the .FindOne() Method to stop as soon as a match is found 

Dim sr As SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()  

If sr Is Nothing Then 'return false if user isn't found 
lblStatus.Text = "User authentication failed" 
Return False 
End If 
Dim de As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = sr.GetDirectoryEntry() 
sUserName = de.Properties("GivenName").Value.ToString() 

lblStatus.Text = "User authentication success" 

Return True  'Valid user 

Catch ex As Exception ' return false if exception occurs 
lblStatus.Text = "User authentication failed" 

Return False 

End Try 

End Function
```

How can I know whether the code is working or not? Do I have to make a login form?

Comment: Create a function that includes the minimum logic (e.g. DirectoryService but no UI elements) and parameter (Domain Name, User Name) which returns true or false (based on dirSearcher.FindOne()) . Create another function (or Unit Test) which calls the first function. The second function can be just a Console Application e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a form with a textbox/label = lblStatus and run the function.